# Can spells cast from items be used with feats relevant to the spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, feats, metamagic

In Pathfinder, can you use a **Ring of Dimension Door** in conjunction with the **Dimensional Dervish** feat tree? I'd like to know if I'd get more use (and value) out of such a ring than a Ring of Wizardry IV.

That's the specific example I'm thinking of, but a general rule would also be appreciated.

Comment: Can a link be provided to the *ring of dimension door*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a house rule, no, you cannot combine them. [Dimensional Dervish](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/dimensional-dervish/) and all of the other feats in the tree have the requirement -

> Prerequisites: Ability to use the abundant step class feature or cast dimension door

Activating an item is generally not the same thing as casting a spell, and will not allow you to fulfill that prerequisite. And, even if you could fill the requirement and learn the feat, the feats all work from either using abundant step or casting dimension door.

Comment: I can cast the spell all right, just needed to know if getting it out of an item worked the same way.

Answer (score 0):

A Ring of Dimension Door wouldn't work(RAW), but a (Greater, Minor) Ring of Spell Storing with Dimension Door(s) in it would.

Activating a magic item is not 'casting' per this (emphasis added) line from Dimensional Dervish

> You can take a full-attack action, activating abundant step or **casting dimension door** as a swift action.

If you want to have more uses per day than you have spell slots/Ki for Abundant Step, you could use a Ring of Spell Storing which indicates

> A ring of spell storing contains up to 5 levels of spells (either divine or arcane, or even a mix of both spell types) that the wearer can **cast**...

That all said, it's worth petitioning the GM for; there is little chance of it breaking a game and could go a long way toward fulfilling certain character concept goals.

*Of course neither item qualifies you for the feat(s), but that doesn't seem to be what your question is referring to.*

Comment: There's also the ring of Wizardry IV, which doubles level 4 spell slots. Actually the combo I have in mind could potentially break the game, I'm trying to ride the bleeding edge between superlative optimisation and total ruination.

Comment: @CaptainSkylock I find it hard to believe that Dimensional Dervish could break your game... it's a powerful ability for sure, but there are ways to counter it. Having a handful more uses of it per day with a price-tag in the tens of thousands is hardly more powerful than any other build with a way to full attack and move (Unch Monk, Beast Totem Barbarian, etc)

Comment: Monks and Barbarians don't get 11d6 sneak attack, solo flanking, adaptable Bane weapon, the ability to provoke their own AoOs during their own full attack (by crit-fishing), while casting Disintegrate at the same time.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear how you're using Rogue, Inquisitor, AND 6th level arcane spells all in one action, let alone on one character. Also, Seize the Moment doesn't trigger from yourself. It doesn't matter if you're flanking 'with yourself', you're still not another ally. Otherwise it would trigger from your own criticals without Dimensional Dervish (it technically does, RAW, since you count as your own Ally... GL convincing the GM of that)

Comment: Spiderhawk Archetype for Magus (sneak attack, spell combat, arcane spells), using Outflank rather than Seize the Moment, and taking Bane as an Arcane Pool ability. Paizo ruling says 'You count as your own ally unless otherwise stated or if doing so would make no sense or be impossible. Thus, “your allies” almost always means the same as “you and your allies.' Using an ability that explicitly states you are flanking with yourself is surely such an occasion.

Comment: Applying either benefit, but especially the AoO from Outflank could easily fall under 'make no sense or be impossible'. Spiderhawk gets 7d6 sneak attack up to 10d6 if you take 3x Accomplished Sneak Attacker plus the Dimensional Dervish Feats means that's pretty much all you're doing... assuming you have Close Range arcana, Riddle in the Steel (arguably only for one or a few creature types) (because you can't have Bane Blade)... assuming your GM is really nice... you might do a little more than an equivalent level Barbarian sometimes. With that much investment, you've earned it lol.

Comment: I thought casting Sense Vitals by taking Spell Blending would be more efficient than Accomplished Sneak attacker. I get my pick of +1 weapon properties to apply at level 5, so I take Bane then and there. Bane-on-command abilities such as this or what the Inquisitor and Occultist have can have their creature type chosen each time you turn it on. Taking Cloying Shades and Petrifying Strike to pile on dex damage and penalties would make landing hits easier, and scary if I can get Calcific Touch too.

Comment: That makes sense. At that point, you're using tactical application of spells to set up your combo. Definitely a good magus build. I missed the flexible Arcane Pool... that seems a little too powerful. 'Course that's what I expect from 3pp. Anyway, I don't have any more mechanical concerns. Good luck with your d6 bomb.